# "Failed to parse time string" The timezone could not be found in the databse - Laravel

Tags: laravel, database

I'm trying to migrate my old laravel project to a new server. I've installed PHP, mysql, cache software and I've imported the database. After importing the mysql database I received this error when running PHP ARTISAN MIGRATE

> In Carbon.php line 511:
>
> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (database.sq) at position 0 (d): The ti
> mezone could not be found in the database

I've looked in the carbon.php file located in app/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon. It's possible that a different server configuration or PHP version is causing this?

Comment: The stack trace will likely show you where the problem is coming from. "database.sq" is clearly not a valid time string.